# Is it possible to change the dimensions of my fabricjs canvas onclick?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I've got my fabricjs canvas set in JS as `canvas.setHeight(616);
canvas.setWidth(446);` and I was wondering if there was a way that I could enable the user to change these dimensions onclick, so that there are a few options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('a');
canvas.add(new fabric.Text('FabricJS is Awsome',{
 left:50,
 top:50
}));

function resizeCanvas(){
 canvas.setHeight(canvas.height+50);
 canvas.setWidth(canvas.width+50);
 canvas.renderAll();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.js"></script>
<button onclick='resizeCanvas()'>Resize</button>
<canvas id="a" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Use [setHeight()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#setHeight) / [setWidth()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#setWidth) to set height and width respectively.